# Why can I ping but not curl from one to another docker container, which are in the same network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So, I've basically set up **two containers**, one is running a web app with an API endpoint, the other one, for the sake of the example, should just emulate a, let's say web app client.

I've connected both containers into **one bridged network**.

```
...
"Driver": "bridge",
...
```

And both containers are within the network.

```
"Containers": {
            "some-id": {
                "Name": "webapp-api-container",
                "IPv4Address": "some-ip",
            },
            "some-id-2": {
                "Name": "webapp-client-container",
            }
```

Also, the web app API container does have open ports.

Now, I can ping the web app running container, by its name or by the IP address which you find when inspecting the network and that's great. But I'm trying to curl the container on a specific port and API endpoint, and it fails with `Connection refused`

It's weird because I can curl the endpoint on the given port from the host without issues.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you started any web server on that container?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing what how you start the containers and what the actual URL you're connecting to is?

Comment: test that the web app is running on the right NIC (and not on the localhost loopback)

Comment: Have you checked the web app binded port? Does it listen to 127.0.0.1:PORT? If yes, then the web app container can not be accessed by other containers.